# Error installing scipy with pip

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I have tried installing scipy using pip install scipy. I have installed all the dependencies, gcc-fortran, lapack-devel, blas-devel but to no avail. I created my virtual environment with pyvenv-3.4. Anytime I try installing scipy it hangs after these two lines

```
 Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
 Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy
```

On one trial, I waited all night and it did not install. My OS is CentOS-7. Thanks for your help.

After getting some help, I tried easy_install scipy. Same problem it stops somewhere and just hangs. I have to depress Ctrl+C to escape. How do I finish installing or reinstall it? Thanks.

Edit:

I finally fixed it by following the instructions here: http://chrisstrelioff.ws/sandbox/2014/06/04/install_and_setup_python_and_packages_on_ubuntu_14_04.html

Comment: try install it using  `easy_install scipy`

Comment: Have you tried passing the `-v` flag to force `pip` to print compilation messages?

Comment: I am using pyvenv-3.4 because I want to use python3. How I install easy_install in pip? Thanks.

Comment: You don't install easy_install with pip, it is a separate installer that should already be installed.

Comment: I am confused. So what would be the command to install scipy(easy _install or pip)? Keep in mind that I am using pyvenv 3.4 to set up my virtual environment. How do I get past the hanging part or how do I use either effectively? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It comes with many packages for scientists. SciPy works out of the box. Just install as user not root. It comes with `conda` which is an improved `virtualenv`.

If you don't want all packages of Anaconda  use [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html)

You can create a new environment and install `scipy`:

```
conda create -n my_project python=3.4
source activate my_project
conda install scipy
```

No compilation involved.

Comment: Thanks. I did not use Anaconda. I used virtualenvwrapper instead.